# Reducing the complexity of dictionary brute force in python

Tags: python, dictionary, cryptography, complexity-theory, brute-force

I have a program as follows which basically compares XORs of all possible words in a standard dictionary and compares the XORed result with that of XOR of Ciphertexts.But i guess the complexity is O(n2). I am not sure how to reduce the complexity.

```
def find_collision():
    a = int("4ADD55BA941FE954",16) ^ int("5AC643BE8504E35E",16)
    with open("/usr/share/dict/words", "r") as f:
        alist = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
    b = len(alist)

    for i in range(0,b,1):
        for j in range(i,b,1):
        if(((int(alist[i].encode('hex'), 16))^ (int(alist[j].encode('hex'), 16)))==a):
            print("Plain Text1: "+alist[i]+'\n'+"Plain Text2: "+alist[j])
            #print "Yes"
            break
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't need to know WHICH keys collide, just if ANY keys collide, you could toss them all in a `set` together and see if the length of the `set` is the same as the length of the `list`

Comment: @adsmith I quite did not understand what you said :( May I request you to rephrase it.

Comment: I don't really understand what your code is trying to do, either. It looks like it takes `0x4ADD55BA941FE954^0x5AC643BE8504E35E` (which is `0b1000000011011000101100000010000010001000110110000101000001010`) and comparing it to each two items in `dict/words` XOR'd together, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, let's try to simplify.

```
def find_collision():
    key = 0b1000000011011000101100000010000010001000110110000101000001010
    # that's 0x4ADD55BA941FE954^0x5AC643BE8504E35E
```

Then our handy-dandy `itertools` module can do the heavy lifting for the big list. This replaces your nested `for` loops and probably works significantly faster.

```
from itertools import combinations
##def find_collision()
##    key = 0b1000000011011000101100000010000010001000110110000101000001010
with open("/usr/share/dict/words", "r") as f:
    full_wordlist = combinations( map(str.rstrip,f.readlines()), 2 )
    # Combinations( { ('word1','word2'),('word1','word3'),('word1','word4'),
                    ('word2','word3') ... } )
```

But we don't really care about the whole thing, do we? All we care about is collisions, so let's do collisions shall we? **EDIT:** and since there will definitely be words in here we can't turn to hex, do:

```
#instead of full_wordlist = combinations(...)

import re
with open("usr/share/dict/words","r") as f:
    words = (word for word in map(str.rstrip,f.readlines()) if not re.search(r"[^0-9a-fA-F]",word))
    # you can avoid the need for regex by doing:
    # words = (word for word in map(str.rstrip,f.readlines()) if
    #         not any(char not in "0123456789abcdefABCDEF" for char in word))
    collisions = [keypair for keypair in combinations(words,2)
                 if bin(int(keypair[0],base=16)^int(keypair[1],base=16)) == key]
```

Then pull out the collisions with something sane, like:

```
for collision in collisions:
    print("Collision between {0[0]}^{0[1]} and key".format(collision))
```

Comment: Oops that last listcomp would have always returned a `TypeError`, as it was trying to do `str^str`. I fixed it.

Comment: But I am getting this error ..  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    find_collision()
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 7, in find_collision
    if bin(int(keypair[0],base=16)^int(keypair[1],base=16)) == key]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: "A's"

Comment: Sounds like one of the words in your dictionary is `"A's"`. That won't work, for obvious reasons. You can probably make a generator earlier that pulls from your word list. I'll edit....

Comment: @user2888239 I've edited, this is one way to do it. There's probably a better way, though. I'll keep thinking.